# Can you assign a value directly to a bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am trying to reproduce an assignment in Java code with an equivalent bean definition in Spring.  As far as I can tell, though, Spring only lets you assign values to the fields within an object (provided that the class defines the appropriate setter methods).  Is there a way to simply capture a reference to an object using Spring beans?

Here's an example of how I would expect this to work:

```
<!-- Non-working example. -->
<bean id="string" class="java.lang.String">
    <value>"I am a string."</value>
</bean>
```

I realize that in this particular case I could just use a `<constructor-arg>`, but I'm looking for more general solution, one that also works for classes that don't provide parameterized constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to use here is a `factory-method`, possibly in conjunction with a `factory-bean`.  (Non-static functions must be instantiated by a bean of the appropriate type.)  In my example problem, I wanted to capture the output of a function that returns a String.  Let's say the function looks like this:

```
class StringReturner {
    public String gimmeUhString(String inStr) {
        return "Your string is: " + instr;
    }
}
```

First I need to create a bean of type `StringReturner`.

```
<bean name="stringReturner" class="how.do.i.java.StringReturner" />
```

Then I instantiate my String bean by calling the desired function as a `factory-method`.  You can even provide parameters to the factory method using `<constructor-arg>` elements:

```
<bean id="string" factory-bean="stringReturner" factory-method="gimmeUhString">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>I am a string.</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

This is (for my purposes) equivalent to saying:

```
StringReturner stringReturner = new StringReturner();
String string = stringReturner.gimmeUhString("I am a string.");
```

Answer (score 2):

String class is immutable. No property `setter method` is available in java.lang.String class. If you want to inject the property value you can use below:

```
<bean id="emp" class="com.org.emp">
    <property name="name" value="Alex" />
</bean>
```

in above for the obj emp, its name property will be set as Alex.

Answer (score 0):

String is not a Bean, Bean is a Objet that his Class that have a Constructor with empty arguments and the properties are accessible by Getters Methods and are modifiable by Setters Methods